# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "odiar" y "odiar a"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos, preposiciones

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "Odio XXX" y "Odio **a** XXX"?  ¿Hay alguna regla para identificar el uso más correcto?  Supongo que la misma pregunta también se aplica a otros verbos como *amar*, etc.

Comment: Efectivamente, cuando dices Odio a... te refieres a que odias a una persona, animal o cosa, pero cuando dices solamente odio estas hablando de algo generalista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En mi opinión, cuando usas `odio a` se refiere a personas o animales, y con `odio` solamente, se refiere a objetos, en esta calificación entraría todo lo demás, como acciones. `Ej. Odio comer, odio ir a la panadería,etc`.

Agregando un poco más:

> Odio ese sofá.
>
> Odio a ese niño.

"A" se usa con personas y no con objetos.

Comment: Bien contestada, Mary.  Pienso que quedaría mejor aún si explicaras el principio de ***a** con personas pero no con objetos*.

Comment: realmente es el mismo principio lo que un poco más feo con odio así qe utilizaré amo.  Yo amo a mi esposo, amo a mis hijos, amo a mis gatos, si eres a "cat person", como se dice en inglés

Comment: Mary, puedes editar lo que agregué si quieres.

Comment: Habría que matizar también que con "a" se refiere a personas o animales concretos. Se puede decir "Odio a ese perro", pero si lo que odias son los perros en general, sería "Odio los perros" y no "Odio a los perros". En el caso de los objetos, da igual si se trata de un objeto concreto o en general, por lo que se dice "Odio ese bolígrafo", como también se dice "Odio los bolígrafos".